# My dataframe is not saved properly with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

This is my code

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import MySQLdb

todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')

columns = ['John','Pierre', 'Boris']

df_ = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0)
data = np.array([np.arange(10)]*3).T

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

print (df)

con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="milenko",passwd="*******",db="dbase")

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://milenko:"+'*******'+"@localhost/dbase")
df.to_sql(con=engine,name = 'stek', if_exists='fail', index=True)
```

My df looks like

```
       John  Pierre  Boris
2017-06-06     0       0      0
2017-06-07     1       1      1
2017-06-08     2       2      2
2017-06-09     3       3      3
2017-06-10     4       4      4
2017-06-11     5       5      5
2017-06-12     6       6      6
2017-06-13     7       7      7
2017-06-14     8       8      8
2017-06-15     9       9      9
```

But this is confusing.My table looks like this

```
show columns from  stek;
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| index  | datetime   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| John   | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Pierre | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Boris  | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Did I make a mistake? Where?What I really want is to perserve the whole dataframe structure in order to use this method for much larger datasets.
My query

```
 SELECT FROM stek WHERE index = 'John';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM stek WHERE index = 'John'' at line 1
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Your dataframe's structure was preserved according to what you've pasted here. Your dataframe had an datetime index and 3 columns: John, Pierre, and Boris. The table reflects that. Out of interest, why do you create both a MySQLdb connection and an SQLAlchemy engine? Is unpivoting ([pandas.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)) what you're really after?

Comment: @IljaEverilä That line was from not deleted,my efforts with MySQLdb.Can you just print an answer how should I query my columns?

Comment: I've no idea what to answer. Your table structure is your dataframe's structure. What is the problem? Do you not know how to query in SQL?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Take a look at my edit!

Comment: You're missing the select list from your SELECT. Try `SELECT * FROM ...` for starters. Your `index` column is a datetime column, it does not contain 'John'. If you want John's data, `SELECT John FROM stek`. Still, I think what you're really after is unpivoting your dataframe to a table of `index, name, value` rows. Your attempt at `index = 'John'` hints at such.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes,I understand now,works perfect.